# How to authenticate spring boot rest API from Frontend react which uses single sign on

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, spring-security, single-sign-on

I am implementing the full stack development project with Frontend as React and Backend as Spring boot. Frontend react application is hosted on IIS server and Spring boot is hosted on Apche tomcat server. I will be configuring the Frontend (React) application to use organization single sign on(SSO) method for authentication into Frontend GUI and get the user details from SSO. And I also wanted to have backend spring boot application secured using Spring security (probably JWT as I understand). Below are my concerns.

1. If I configure Spring security then it prompts for user authentication which I do not have credentials to pass it in http request from React as user authentication is from SSO.
2. Is there better approach of using SSO on the backend (spring boot)? If so how do I route the user from React to spring boot for authentication.

3. Any suggestions for best way to implement Authentication using SSO for both React and Spring boot.

Please note that SSO is mandatory to use it for user authentication to access the Frontend.

I would appreciate any help provided for my need.

Comment: `organization single sign on(SSO) method for authentication` this makes no sense. How to you expect us to answer any questions when you havnt even told us how authentication is done. Also handing out JWTs to the frontend client is a massive security risk, if token gets stolen you have no way of revoking it. The client should never authenticate straight the the issuer. How will you ensure that its your client authenticating, and not someone elses bogus client? This entire setup is very insecure, hope you are aware of that.

Comment: @Toerktumlare, Thank you for your response, if you can could you please suggest me better approach I can handle with?

Comment: I suggest you read the oauth2 rfc specification, and then you read the JWT rfc specification

Comment: @Toerktumlare, would you mind helping me this question https://stackoverflow.com/q/72832549/19377392